# Why would empty results be shown when using IS NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, vbscript

I'm using the below code however empty results are shown even when using `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT COLUMN1
       ,COLUMN2
       ,COLUMN3
    FROM TABLE.DBF
    WHERE COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY COLUMN1 ASC
```

Example result:

```
     50 0
     51 0
     50 0
     51 0
     50 0
     51 0
1    50 35000
1    51 29334.71
10   50 10000
10   51 1568.14
100  50 25000
100  51 -2731.98
```

If I switch this to `> 0` then the empty results are not shown. Ideally `IS NOT NULL` would be better to use as it makes more sense. How can I make it work? There is **nothing** in that column for that row.

Example result using `> 0` instead of `IS NOT NULL`:

```
1    50 35000
1    51 29334.71
10   50 10000
10   51 1568.14
100  50 25000
100  51 -2731.98
```

Comment: Are you sure column1 is actually NULL, and not just an empty string? `null` is very much different from `''`.

Comment: @MarcB `NULL` is nothing the last time I checked, no? If I use a GUI and click in that field there is no space at the start or anything, so that's `NULL`, or not?

Comment: Because Null does equal " ". If you want that to work you would have to update the database and make all " " = null

Comment: which data type is assigned to your column?

Comment: Please cross-check if the `COLUMN1` field of those rows actually is `NULL`: `SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 FROM TABLE.DBF WHERE COLUMN1 IS NULL`. Do the rows show up in the output? What DBMS are you using? Also, please show the definition of `TABLE.DBF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
WHERE COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL and COLUMN1 <>''
```

and see if that changes your results.

Answer (score 2):

If this is T-SQL (MS SQL-server) you can use `nullif()` as shown in the example below. `nullif()` in this example returns `NULL` if the value is an empty string.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 
FROM TABLE.DBF 
WHERE NULLIF(COLUMN1,'') IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY COLUMN1 ASC
```